# Google Analytics Social Interactions

Tags: google-analytics

I've juste set up social interactions tracking (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/social-interactions)

Do these interactions go up in the real time reports ?
Where are the non-real time reports ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't believe these interactions show up in real time reports unless they are also being tracked as "Events" -- then they would show up under Real Time > Events.

2) If you've setup social interactions correctly, the report you're looking for should be under Acquisition > Social > Plugins -- Depending on when you set this up, it could be several hours before you start seeing results.